# Shuffle part of a jQuery object but return the whole object

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jQuery object, I'd like to shuffle all elements but the first. After different attempts I came up with this:

```
var $shuffled = $('.slide').slice(1).shuffle().end();
```

However this returns an empty object. How can I first select part of an object (slice), then shuffle it (custom function) and then set back the filter (end) so that $shuffled returns the whole object and not just a subset of it?

This is the shuffle code I use:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });

        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you show your shuffle code, you call it (custom function)? Are you using a jQuery plugin?

Comment: I added the shuffle code. I tested it separately and it works.

Comment: I'm looking at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/end/), and I don't think .end() returns anything. It's used to finish working with a filter. In this case you're resetting your call chain back to the last filtering method `.slice(1)` but not *returning* that query.

Comment: that `shuffle` plugin looks somewhat brittle - I'd be wary of using `.clone` to duplicate elements to achieve something that should be perfectly achievable in place.

Comment: @Alnitak I've found this function on [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/). Does [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R2fNC/) look better to you?

Comment: @worc I noticed that .end() only ends the most recent filter. My hope was to find a way to chain the slice and shuffle without having to split up the object into two variables and put it back together after the shuffle.

Comment: @user648519 it's somewhat better, although the author deserves a bollocking for using `parseInt` as a rounding function in the expression `parseInt(Math.random() * i)`.  Note that the new version specifically just shuffles all children of the given element, not those in the selector itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a simple solution myself. I didn't realize that [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) is what I'm looking for. Here's what it looks like now:

```
var $slides = $('.slide');
var $firstSlide = $slides.slice(0,1);
var $remainingSlides = $slides.slice(1).shuffle();

$slides = $firstSlide.add($remainingSlides);
```

Not as nice as a one-liner, but at least quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

The commenter is right, I don't believe `end()` is doing what you expect it to do.

Here is my solution, it could probably be optimized, but it completes the request at hand.

```
var $shuffled = [];
var allSlides = $('.slide');
var $first = allSlides.first();
$shuffled.push($first);
var $rest = allSlides.slice(1).shuffle().each(function(){
    $shuffled.push($(this));    
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle to Test the solution http://jsfiddle.net/gndgo6us/1/

On successive runs you can see the HTML change to show the shuffling.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work in my setup yet. As far as I can see it returns an array, not a jQuery object, right?